# Как убрать конкретный текст из переменной на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```py
#есть текст
text = ("hello world")
print(text)
```

как мне удалить из переменной слово `hello`?

Comment: text = text.replace('hello', '')

Answer (score 2):

```
text = ("hello world")[6:]
print(text)
```